# Pointing a domain name using an A Record to a Bitnami LAMP Module on AWS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami, a-records

I have Bitnami LAMP stack running on AWS. I have installed Wordpress in a folder called /wordpress/ using a downloaded Bitnami installer. It is visible publicly through the url: 11.11.111.11/wordpress/. I have set up an A Record for a domain name to point to the IP address. The result is that the site now is visible through the URL: mydomain.com/wordpress/.

Problem is that I want it to be visible via the url: mydomain.com (without the /wordpress/ folder).

I have tried everything that I have found on the topic for 2 days and simply cannot solve this seemingly simple task. I'm happy to provide more info on request. Please can someone help!

EDIT

I have the following two Apache configuration files:

1. opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf
   with content:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

   Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName mydomain.com
   ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
   DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/certs/server.key"

   Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf"
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf
   with content:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]

   <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
   <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock|fcgi://wordpress-fpm" timeout=300>
   </Proxy>
   </IfDefine>

   <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
   Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   <IfVersion < 2.3 >
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </IfVersion>
   <IfVersion >= 2.3>
       Require all granted
   </IfVersion>

   <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
     <FilesMatch \.php$>
       SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://wordpress-fpm"
     </FilesMatch>
   </IfDefine>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /wordpress/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]

   </Directory>

   Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf"
   ```

The result is that mydomain.com (registered at Godaddy) points to the root and not the wordpress directory.

My understanding of Apache is that vhosts allows you to point a domain to a document root folder and have multiple domains pointing to a single server IP address. So I don't see why this does not work.

Comment: DNS simply translates domain names to IP addresses. You can't "point a domain name" to a folder on your server. You will need to change your web server configuration to serve your Wordpress site as the root.

Comment: yes I know but nothing seems to work in the context of bitnami lamp. I have tried configuring vhost as per bitnami documentation but get server errors.

Comment: If you want more help you are probably going to need to post your configuration and go into detail about what you have tried.

Comment: @Mark B. I have added the config files as requested.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Maybe this can help someone.

Do not use the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf config file, but instead use the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf and run the following command:

```
    sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --appurl /
```